# Removing chart on click event produces 'removeHoverStyle' of null error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

My base chart wrapper looks like this (using ReactJS 16.8+ with ChartJS 2.0+)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);
function BarChart({ chartId, options }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const myChart = new Chart(chartId, options); // instantiate a new chart
    return () => {
      myChart.destroy(); // destroy chart on component unmount
    };
  });

  return (
    <canvas className={classes.chart} id={chartId} data-testid={chartId}>
      <p>{t('noCanvasSupport')}</p>
    </canvas>
  );
}
```

The options object that I pass in has an onClick callback function that changes one of the parent's state variables (a boolean). This conditionally renders one of the charts below.

```
function Parent() {
...
return (
<>
    {isTrue && <Barchart options={{...}} chartId={'chart-1'} />} // throws error as soon as isTrue becomes false
    {!isTrue && <Barchart options={{...}} chartId={'chart-2'} />}
</>
)
}
```

I seem to be getting this error when isTrue is changed (through the onclick callback function that is triggered when clicking one of the bars in the chart) and the first Barchart is unmounted. The removeHoverStyle gets called for some reason

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeHoverStyle' of null
    at Chart.updateHoverStyle (Chart.js:8801)
    at Chart.handleEvent (Chart.js:8883)
    at Chart.eventHandler (Chart.js:8820)
    at listener (Chart.js:8758)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.proxies.<computed> (Chart.js:6685)
```

Options object:

```
const options = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    data: data,
    options: {
      onClick: handleChartClick,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      cornerRadius: 6,
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        callbacks: {
          label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
            let label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
            if (label) {
              label += ': ';
            }
            label += `${(tooltipItem.xLabel * 100).toFixed(1)}%`;
            return label;
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontSize: theme.spacing(2) - 2,
          boxWidth: theme.spacing(2) + 2,
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          align: context => {
            if (isSmallScreen && context.datasetIndex === 1 && context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] < 0.1) {
              return 'start';
            } else {
              return 'start';
            }
          },
          anchor: 'end',
          color: '#000000',
          font: {
            size: theme.spacing(1) + 4,
            family: 'Roboto',
            weight: 'normal',
          },
          formatter: (value, context) => {
            return (value * 100).toFixed(1) + '%';
          },
          display: context => {
            return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 0.05;
          },
        },
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: false,
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true,
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              fontSize: isHeader ? theme.spacing(3) : theme.spacing(2),
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              fontStyle: isHeader ? 'bold' : 'normal',
              padding: theme.spacing(2),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  };
```

Related link https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3777

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I am experiencing this myself. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have exact same issue, and I figured out that we are not supposed to modify chart within onClick event handler, and the solution is

```
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (ref.current) {
                ref.current.chartInstance.destroy();
            }
            history.push(`/eod/${date}`);
        }, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on `react 16.12` with `react-chartjs-2 2.9.0`. I have found that the chart itself has the property "onElementsClick" that you can set a function to handle showing of the chart based on a property in a parent component. This way you don't have to do any kind of weird hacks like randomly delaying execution of code.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const chartComponent = (props) => {
  return (
      <Line onElementsClick={props.handleShow} ..... />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was resolved in React by moving the action that changed the current page on a `setTimeout()` function with a 0 timer. I'm not sure why this solves the issue, perhaps some synchronous process that should be asynchronous. Calling `destroy()` on the chart does not seem to change anything, but I left it as it seems to be a good thing to unmount cleanly the component before changing page.

```js
options.onClick = (_event, activeElements) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    activeElements.length && activeElements[0]._chart.destroy();
    this.props.history.push(`measure/${measure_id}`);
  }, 0);
};
```